# How can I extract a list of dependent tables from an execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan

Is there a way to extract a full list of tables and views used in a query?

I need to replicate a portion of a database so that we can avoid locking tables when a long query runs.

I have the execution plan. Is it possible to extract all the database objects the query touches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was a one-off operation, I would be inclined to use [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) (**it's free!**), rather than faff around writing a SQL Script.

Open the Execution Plan in Plan Explorer, navigate to the Query Columns pane and you can see a list of the objects that are used in the query.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark - that thing's great! Right clicking allowed me to copy it to Excel to muck about with.